How to Setup 2 Domains on a Single Wordpress (Regions Filter)?
I know I can use multi site but what I want to do is different so guide me
My country is filtering my domain regularly and since I'm getting all my traffic from google search I need to change domain every time and losing google rank so now I want to do something different to do not lose my google rank
I have 2 domains
example.com ( this is my main domain which is google seeing it, should have index and follow meta tags )
example.net ( this is my second domain that only My country users will use it so can be change ez when got filtered, should have noindex and nofollow meta tags )
I just create a page rule on cloudflare and set a redirect for users from my country to example.net ( they will see my main domain on google results while searching but when they click it they will redirect to my second domain which is example.net )
What I did so far ?
I've added this code to my wp-config.php
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'example.net') {
    define('WP_HOME', 'https://example.net');
    define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://example.net');
} else {
    define('WP_HOME', 'https://example.com');
    define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://example.com');
}

so this part of code is working fine due to rewriting all files and urls with the second domain
no my another problem to fix is NoIndexing and NoFollowing my second domain to stop duplicate error on google so I did this
since I'm using Rank Math I've added this code to my theme function.php
add_filter('rank_math/frontend/robots', function($robots) {
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] === 'example.net') {
        // Return an array to avoid type errors
        return ['noindex' => 'noindex', 'nofollow' => 'nofollow'];
    }
    return $robots;
});

and adde this line in my theme header.php
    <?php if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'example.net') : ?>
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <?php endif; ?>

now my whole website is available under two domains , without any url confilit
example.com
example.net
and when I check all urls under domain example.com has index and follow meta tags and all urls under example.net does have noindex and nofollow meta tags
I just wanted to know is it ok to do it ?
do I need to anything more? is it enough ?
